# How to automatically copy files in building project with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have some custom made XML files and a read me file that I've included in my project.

How do I make it so that these files are copied to my debug/release folders automatically when I build my project? I've tried setting the Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy Always" but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

I'm using VS2010

Comment: Did you rebuild (not just build) the project after setting `copy always`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes I did, like 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The build action needs to be set to **Content** if you want to just directly copy the file to the output folder.

[image]